# I'm trying to read in a csv file from github in R. However, when I try to get the names of the columns, I only get one name

Tags: r

I'm running this code to import the csv file into movies.

```
movies <-read.csv("https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/fandango/fandango_score_comparison.csv",header=TRUE) 
names(movies)
```

Here I'm trying to get the names of the columns

`{r seeing variable names,echo=FALSE}
names(movies)`

All I get is this

```
[1] "X..DOCTYPE.html."
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reading data from github, you need to pass in the raw version of the data in `read.csv()`, you are using the display version. You can get the URL for the raw version by clicking on the Raw button displayed above the data.

[image]

```
movies <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/fandango/fandango_score_comparison.csv", header=TRUE)
```